# HTML: Multiple name/value for an element?

Tags: html, forms, webforms, get

I've recently come across something like:

- ```
  <form method="get" action="/somewebdir/script.php">
     <input type="radio" name="param0" value="foo" />
     <input type="radio" name="param1" value="foo" />
     <input type="radio" name="param2" value="bar" />
     <input type="radio" name="param2" value="bar" checked="checked" />
  </form>
  ```

I was curious if there was a way to send multiple key/values, if the second param2 is sent, without any JS.
So that the page would result to something like:

- `http://domain/somewebdir/script.php?param2=bar&param3=foobar`

---

I changed the value from `"bar"` to `"bar&amp;param3=foobar"`, but obviously the special chars (`&` and `=`) will be encoded.

Any ideas? (again w/o JS)

---

Hidden elements won't work as it will always send the parameter, which would have a negative affect on other things being called by the handler (script.php)

Comment: You can add hidden inputs with names and values of other parameters which will get sent when the form is submitted.  But this will then always happen, irrespective of which radio button gets checked.

Comment: @Stefan: exactly :), trying to avoid that.  Imagine "script.php" is really a handler, in the best case, it would clutter up the address bar, in the worst case it would have an effect on the content.  In this case I was trying to create a simple `debug` radio button.  For now, I'm setting checkboxes, but to make it clearer for users, I wanted to create a debug column, exactly the same as the previous radio button, but with an added `debug=1` (or something similar param)

Comment: No way to do this without javascript.  You could also split the radio button groups into 2 forms, with the second form having an additional `param3` input with value `foobar`, but then you won't be able to submit both forms with one button.

Comment: I knew it was a long shot and I probably know 99% of the language, but wasn't sure if HTML5 might have something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can't be done. Instead, do it from the server side (as in, expect the input, and if it arrives act accordingly). If it's not coming from the user, it's not user input!

If you need a specific value for each user, you can use a hidden input, and cross check that with your radio button.

```
<input type="hidden" name="param3" value="value here">
```

Comment: Probably will select this because of the `No, it can't be done`

Comment: For any future users coming here: there are better options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes in short: any attribute prepended by "data-" is automatically valid and accesible. Like <input data-param="paramValue01" > etc. This is the poper way to do it in modern browsers

Answer (score 3):

Ususally you'd use a custom delimiter and parse it on the server:

```
<input type="radio" name="param2" value="bar|happy|friday" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a third parameter as a hidden element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="param3" value="foobar" />
```

Then on the server side, check if the second value was "on" (checked) before processing the third parameter.

If the server-side script (script.php) is out of your control and you are required to pass a third parameter if and only if the second parameter is given, you are out of luck without JS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "hidden" element. You can process the extra element as needed.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/hidden

Answer (score 0):

as long as the names of the tags are different, they will get passed as different elements of the $_GET or $_POST array...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="/somewebdir/script.php">
   <input type="radio" name="param0" value="foo" />
   <input type="radio" name="param1" value="foo" />
   <input type="radio" name="param2[]" value="bar" />
   <input type="radio" name="param2[]" value="bar" checked="checked" />
</form>
```

---

if (isset ($_POST['param2']))           {$param2 = $_POST['param2'];}
$param2= implode(" ",$param2);

```
echo $param2;
```